# iCloud: Losing permission to write to a file if it is modified on another machine while open locally

Tags: macos, cocoa, icloud

I have iCloud document sharing mostly working with Mac OS X; I can save and read documents and updates on one machine move to the other machine. The only problem at this point is that if the same document is open on two machines and one of the machines updates the document the other machine is no longer able to save the document unless it is closed and re-opened. There is an error displayed saying that I don't have permission to write to the document. I've been looking through the documentation and I haven't found anything yet that looks like it would solve the problem.
I call: `[NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:self];` When the file is opened, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Has anyone else run across this issue and found a solution?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I keep going back to the documentation, but I've had no luck finding a solution so far. The iOS equivalent of my test application does not exhibit this behavior: modifications move, seamlessly from iOS device to iOS device, and iOS device to Mac. But, on the Mac, as soon as either my iOS test app, or another instance of my Mac test application accesses the file ... permissions error! However, I can use any _other_ Mac application to open and edit the file without this problem manifesting. Obviously, something is set up incorrectly in one, or all, of the test apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in 10.7.2 that has been fixed in 10.7.3 so if you run into the same problem just make sure you are on 10.7.3 or later.